# Rebalance the following AVL tree after inserting G. You need to show the middle step if it happens. Briefly explain the operations

Tags: trees, binary-search-trees, avl-trees

I recently learned AVL Trees but I still lack a complete understanding of the concept. I understand that an AVL tree is a Binary search tree that checks for the height of the tree, but I still don't understand how I would apply that to the question. Any help is appreciated!

[image: Rebalance the following AVL tree after inserting G. You need to show the middle step if it happens. Briefly explain the operations.]

Comment: You might want to make the question clearer? What do you mean here by middle step?

Comment: That's also a part I'm confused on. The question has no prior question that it's connected to, nor does it elaborate beyond what is shown within my post. I'm sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: @Thomas This is a blunt question. There are many books and online resources to how to balance an AVL tree. You need to tell us what efforts you made and where exactly you got stuck. Also, please consider adding the question in the main body of your post.